# Migrating the spell check from one installation of Visual Studio 2010 to another?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 underlines any misspelled words in red, you can add these to the built in spelling dictionary to remove the underline in red.

I'd like to migrate the spelling dictionary from my old install of Visual Studio 2010 to my new PC. Is this possible?

**Update:**

The spell check feature is part of VAssistX. I've asked the question on the forum, here:
http://www.wholetomato.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=10174

Comment: Do you use [Spell Checker](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7c8341f1-ebac-40c8-92c2-476db8d523ce) VS addin?

Comment: I believe this is an add-on, not a built in feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from http://www.wholetomato.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=10174

> If you mean your custom words dictionary you can simply copy the
>   "UserWords.txt" file from the old PC to the new PC. If you want the
>   language dictionaries, you can either copy them or download fresh
>   ones.
>
> The files live in this directory:
>
> Vista/Windows 7:
>   C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\VisualAssist\Dict\ Windows
>   2000/XP: C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Application
>   Data\VisualAssist\Dict\
>
> and see here for more details:
>
> http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/misspelled.asp